# IBM MobileFirst Add envirnment via ant script

Tags: ant, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

Is there a way to add environment (android,windows and IOS) using ant with the help of any jar Files.

> Like we create .wlapp,.war and .adpater files with the help of
>   worklight-ant-builder.jar

I can do this via mfp CLI but i need to do it with out MFP CLI installed in my system just with the help of any jar files or ant ant files.

Comment: Can you explain why u need to create environment without using MFP CLI. Is any specific reason behind for this?

Comment: we are trying to automise the build and deploy process via ant and bat and we need to keep the resources (i.e) the files needed to do this as minimum as possible but MFP alone cost me 700mb so i need some work around.

Comment: I believe creating the environment will not be the part of Auto Build/Deploy.

Comment: i am exporting things from SVN and trying to automate the rest of the process without eclispe

Comment: You have to understand the Build process. Creating environment is at Development time. When you say build which indicates that you have completed the development. You must use an automation tool with Workligh-ant-builder.jar for building the project which is in SVN.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to add an environment as part of the build. That is a *development-time* task, not a *build-time* task. Please can you clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ant tasks are meant only for building the project artifacts or deploying the project artifacts. They are not meant for development-time.

For development, there is either Studio or CLI.

Comment: Thank you for this info is there any specific libraries in the CLI i can use to do the task without having the whole CLI

Comment: As such you cannot find any specific task and also I wouldn't recommend you to do because this may cause a new issue.

Comment: To run the CLI, you need the CLI installed.